# Dynamic dropdown from another spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, drop-down-menu

With this script I can auto populate a dropdown from a spreadsheet to another but it is limited to import in the dropdown only 500 values, I need it for more values.

In addition, when I run it, it works on the cells that I have selected in the destination sheet.
How to set up a specific range for the dropdown, for example the entire column C?

```
function importSheetA() { 
  return SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxx')
                       .getSheetByName('xxxxx')
                       .getRange('xxxxx')
                       .getValues()
                       .flat(); // This ensures a simple array is returned
}

function populateDropdown() {
  var values = importSheetA();
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
                           .requireValueInList(values, true)
                           .setAllowInvalid(false)
                           .build();
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  range.setDataValidation(rule);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function importSheetA() { 
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('ssid');
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const rg=sh.getRange(1,3,sh.getLastRow());
  return rg;//passing range now
}

function populateDropdown() {
  const rg=importSheetA();
  const rule=SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(rg).setAllowInvalid(false).build();
  const range=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  range.clearDataValidations();
  range.setDataValidation(rule);  
}
```

Perhaps you could implement something like this as a workaround:

```
function importSheetA() { 
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('ssid')
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const rg=sh.getRange(1,3,sh.getLastRow());
  return rg.getValues();
}

function populateDropdown() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('validationsheet');//local sheet for storing remote validation values
  sh.getDataRange().clear();//optional it is noticeably slower
  const v=importSheetA();
  const rg=sh.getRange(1,1,v.length,1);
  rg.setValues(v);
  const rule=SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(rg).setAllowInvalid(false).build();
  const range=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  range.clearDataValidations();
  range.setDataValidation(rule);  
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but there is the same error for a limit of 500 values in data validation. try yourself.

Comment: I changed it to require values in range like the error suggested and now it works.

Comment: Before I use it, where I can write the spreadsheet source Id?

Comment: Ok. I have tried, but nothing.. I have the source spreadsheet data in column C, and I would to put them in the destination spreadsheet dropdown entire col B

Comment: It's looking like the range has to be in the same spreadsheet to work

Comment: ? With my script, the spreadsheet were different and it worked. The problem was only the limit of the 500 data values...

Comment: It looks like if you want to get beyond that limit that you will have to use a range in the same spreadsheet

Comment: And so it is not possible in different spreadsheet?

Comment: I'm thinking that you could pass the values to a range inside the active spreadsheet and then use that range in that spreadsheet.  So you would need an intermediate step but I think you could get it to work.

Comment: My goal is load a data from different spreadsheet in the dropdown, cause I would to avoid to overload the same sheet and so there is no sense to have a script to populate a dropdown in the same sheet, the normal dropdown already can load from a range in another tab in the same spreadsheet..

Comment: I understand you goal.  But if you know of a way around the 500 item limit feel free to implement it

Comment: I don't understand what your saying

Comment: I will try another solution

Comment: Really I have to agree with Marios 8K choices is ridiculously large.  I would rethink my entire design

Comment: A database linked to the dropdown, could be a solution?

Comment: There's no `requireValue`  in dataValidationBuilder that hooks up directly to a database so you're still going to have to go through a local range in the same spreadsheet.  I think the answer is to rethink the design and perhaps add different categories of data so as to limit the total number in a given drop down.

Comment: I know that the tendency is to try to use what you already have but sometimes you have to just save it somewhere and start all over again.   But these are all design issues and I don't really know enough about what you're doing to be useful and that's not what this forum is for.

Comment: @Popoff  Create and publish a web-app or use  the sidebar to do it in browser  client side  JavaScript. This is better done in JavaScript with onInputChange trigger or autocomplete libraries

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation:

- I would like to assume that your list does **not** consist of more
  than 500 **unique** items. I might well be mistaken though.
- The following script will consider the **unique** values in your data and if the total number of unique values is less than 500, your issue will be resolved.
- To find the unique list of `values` you can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

  `var uniqueValues = values.filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i);`

---

### Solution:

Change `populateDropdown` to this:

```
function populateDropdown() {
  var values = importSheetA();
  var uniqueValues = values.filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i); // <= New code
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
                           .requireValueInList(uniqueValues, true) // <= New code
                           .setAllowInvalid(false)
                           .build();
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  range.setDataValidation(rule);  
}
```

Comment: Hi Marios. My list is about 8000 items. All different from each other..

Comment: may I ask about your goal? Why would you want a dropdown list of 8k items? How is that useful and practical for the end user? He would have to scroll down forever to reach the bottom items. Also consider how heavy the file would be with a dropdown item like that. You can consider grouping your items into different dropdown menus based on some sort of category. @Popoff

Comment: I have a spreadsheet with a lot of rows with the data for various dropdown and so the spreadsheet Is very slow. My goal is to load the dropdown from another spreadsheet in order to avoid to have other tabs with the many data for the dropdown.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to have 8k items in a dropdown menu anyways. I don't think there is solution to your logic, therefore you might need your logic and compromise to the restrictions of google sheets. @Popoff

Comment: With the normal dropdown with the values taken from a range it is possible, also with 8k items but I would use this feature from two different spreadsheets.